# Ubuntu 12.04 slow boot on ASUS, attached with dmesg and bootchart

Tags: 12.04, boot

I heard that Ubuntu can boot up around 30sec, but I take more than 60sec every time my Ubuntu boot. I also read some forum said need to post the dmesg and bootchart to identify which process slowing down the booting time, as I'm not expert in Ubuntu and wish to learn more about it, I humbly ask any pro here to teach me how.

My laptop specs:

```
Model                 : ASUS K45VS
RAM                   : 8MB
CPU                   : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz x 8
Graphic Card          : nVidia GeForce GT 645M
HDD                   : 750GB
OS                    : Single boot Ubuntu 12.04LTS
System.uname          : Linux 3.8.0-39-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:33:40 UTC 2014 x86_64
System.release        : Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
System.kernel.options : BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-39-generic root=UUID=c8a71503-bce8-406c-9a5f-5aa8284f5c7c ro quiet splash
```

My dmesg (which highlighted to the huge time frame gap):

```
[   30.772656] cgroup: libvirtd (1961) created nested cgroup for controller "memory" which has incomplete hierarchy support. Nested cgroups may change behavior in the future.
[   30.772659] cgroup: "memory" requires setting use_hierarchy to 1 on the root.
[   30.772683] cgroup: libvirtd (1961) created nested cgroup for controller "devices" which has incomplete hierarchy support. Nested cgroups may change behavior in the future.
[   30.772710] cgroup: libvirtd (1961) created nested cgroup for controller "blkio" which has incomplete hierarchy support. Nested cgroups may change behavior in the future.
[   32.140335] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   32.505619] ACPI Error: Field [TMPB] at 1081344 exceeds Buffer [ROM1] size 262144 (bits) (20121018/dsopcode-236)
[   32.505624] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._ROM] (Node ffff880224e91f00), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20121018/psparse-537)
[  802.034422] audit_printk_skb: 69 callbacks suppressed
[  802.034428] type=1400 audit(1400914804.392:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1683 comm="cupsd" pid=1683 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
[ 1581.300901] type=1400 audit(1400915584.816:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1683 comm="cupsd" pid=1683 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
```

My Bootchart.png:
[image: Bootchart.png]

Looking forward to learn to improve both my booting time and knowledge. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Things that I notice from the boot chart: clamav, smbd, preload